# Trying to read id_rsa

Tags: github

I am trying to read `cat id_rsa`, but is it throwing

```
cat: id_rsa: Permission denied
```

Also is not letting me push changes to the repository by saying

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am i missing

Answer (score 0):

Need root use permission to read this file so use

```
sudo cat id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with sudo to read the file?

`sudo cat id_rsa.pub`

To my knowledge anyways the ssh key needed for GitHub is the publickey.

To further debug your problem, you might want to make sure that the ssh key is actually added to your github account and has the right permissions.
You can debug if your ssh key is being used with your account by following the steps [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-account)

further steps of debugging the issue that might be helpful can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) (e.g. verifying that your user can make connections after verifying the ssh key)